# Which approach is better for enum values in an XSD? Schema validation or business validation?

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd

For example, I can define an enum, so the XML received is validated ASAP, but if the enum changes , I'll have to expose a new version of the web service.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="MyType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
        <xsd:enumeration value="VALUE_ONE"/> 
        <xsd:enumeration value="VALUE_TWO"/> 
        <xsd:enumeration value="VALUE_THREE"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="Person">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="myType" type="MyType"/> 
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

On the other hand, I could simply have a string type, and validate the values on the backend, returning business errors:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Person">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="myType" type="xs:token"/> 
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Then, if at some point my backend enumerator changes, I should only change the business validations, or just nothing, if the validation just checks whether the value corresponds with one of the values of my backend enum.

Comment: This is a question about trade-offs. What do you gain or loose if you do it one way or the other? I personally don't think you gain much by defining the title in the XSD. As you said yourself, if you change something there, that means a different service contract. Doing versioning just for that is silly. Also, does this service support different languages? Mr. and Mrs. makes sense in English, but not in other languages. Given the almost endless list of values of titles some might want to be called by, I would also think hard if this field is needed (if not a strict business requirement)

Comment: Well, the Mr, Mrs and so on was just a silly example. It would be more for enum values independent of the language. I've updated the code to be more clear.

Comment: Not really a StackOverflow question - you're asking for opinions about good architecture/design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment above, this is a question about trade-offs. You have to ask yourself what you gain and what you loose if you do it one way or the other.

Defining enums like that in the XSD works nicely if you don't need to change the list of accepted values afterwards. If you need to make changes to it, then you can break the contract with the clients, force them to rebuild their proxy clients from the WSDL or force them to implement a different version of your service to make use of the new values. Doing web service versioning for such small changes will be overkill (for clients, for maintenance, etc).

A string type is more flexible. The technical contract is the same, and doesn't need rebuilding and recompiling proxy clients generated from the WSDL, it also removes the need for versioning the contract. I would personally go with this option.

A third alternative, one that I've sometimes used, was to provide additional web service operations or enhanced responses for other operations to also return "meta information". So basically:

- you add another operation to your service, like `<getAvailableTitles>` which returns the list of available titles (the contract remains the same; it's also more type safe than a free input string), or,
- when the  client makes a call to another operation, like, I don't know `<getPersonDetails>` you return the details about the person and also enhance the result with meta information that return the list of titles that you can use when editing the details of the person.

The second approach works best for when things change very often, while the first one works best when things change rarely (the result of the call can even be cached for a while, so clients don't need to call it every time they need to use a title).